# Return boolean value based on the mode

Tags: javascript

I have a probability check to a function, basically I have two modes is it an add or update mode. So the function accepts two params editMode a boolean value and action is an object like `{create: true, read: true}` or `{create: true}` or `{create:true, read: true, update: true}`.

So based on the params passed to the function it should get a boolean value as a return.  Based on the return value I enable or disable the field for the user to type.

I am listing the action and return value for each mode:

```
Add Mode (editMode === false)
probablities
create => false -> user can type 
read => true -> user can't type 
update => true -> user can't type 
create read => false -> user can type 
create update => false -> user can type 
read update => true -> user can't type
create read update => false -> user can type 


Update Mode (editMode === true)
probablities
create => true -> user can't type 
read => true -> user can't type 
update => false -> user can type 
create read => true -> user can't type 
create update => false -> user can type 
read update => false -> user can type
create read update => false -> user can type
```

How should I create a function for this I was using if conditions but is there any better way for this?

So basically the action which is not where the user can't do that action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So without edit mode, the user can type only iff `create` is active, and in edit mode the user can type only iff `update` is active - and `read` doesn't matter at all? So write

```
function userCanType(editMode, action) {
    return editMode ? action.update : action.create;
}
```

Comment: I got the solution I was using object. Keys and checking true or fals

Comment: I will check your solution and will update you thanks for the response

Comment: Yes, `action` is the object with `true` and/or `false` values